# how to pass python json object to django template

Tags: python, django

I want to pass some data(dict format) from views to template. And then in the template I want to transform it to json format, so that it can be used in javascript. But I tried to use json filter, it turns out it is not a valid filter in django. I also tried to use pass a json data in the context  dictionary like this, but I get an error in the template, it says the data is not JSON serializable. i know there is a way to make a another ajax call just to get json data. But I want to get the data in the initial call.

```
    items = models.Model1.objects.all()
    itmes = json.dumps(items)
    return render(request, "index.html", {"items":items})
```

The template I try to use is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = {{ items}};
    $('#table').DataTable( {
        data: data,});
</script>

# model 
class Model1(models.Model):
   token = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   flag = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

Comment: you need to show the data.

Comment: Why are you not using the model serializer?

Comment: The error would be clear: a queryset is not directly JSON serializable, because the `json` library doesn't know anything about Django querysets. That's why, as Ignacio points out, we have the model serializers which are fully documented.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to pass it to template and then transform it to json. You can directly return a string response.

```
import json
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"item":items}))
```

Comment: Yes I try to do that as you said, but I still get the same error.